# Cordova error when adding Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am getting the following error when trying to add android to my cordova project. iOS was working just fine.

$ cordova platform add android
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. An unexpected error occurred: "$ANDROID_BIN" create project --target $TARGET --path "$PROJECT_PATH" --package $PACKAGE --activity $ACTIVITY >&/dev/null exited with 1
Deleting project...

Any ideas what the reason for that can be?

Thanks, Nik

Comment: Using cordova 3.0.0 and Android SDK 17 and 18 are installed.

Answer (score 0):

there was a "-" in the display-name of the app! Seams to be not allowed!

Comment: Could you explain more specifically the steps you took to solve this?